# Are Unix/Linux pipes producer or consumer driven?

Tags: linux, bash, shell, unix, pipe

Suppose I have this:

`A | B | C`

How does the pipeline work? Does A produce data only when B requests it? Does A continually produce data and then block if B can't currently accept it? What's C's role? I realized that a system I'm designing is conceptually very similar to these pipelines -- I'd like to draw upon the existing paradigm rather than inventing something novel that only works half as well.

Comment: would you give some details of your processes ?  if B doesn't read STDIN , then it doesn't matter what A does and same for C

Comment: Yes, B would read from A (and C from B). A and B would also write to `stdout.`

Comment: A , B or C can terminate the pipes as they wish for example:   cat largefile | head -n1 | grep 'test' : only one record is read and all comes to an end

Comment: There are some brief notes about implementation at https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pipeline_(Unix)

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Pipes in Unix have a buffer, so even if the right side process (RSP) does not consume any data, the left side process (LSP) is able to produce a few kilobytes before blocking.

Then, if the buffer gets full, the LSP is eventually blocked. When the RSP reads data it frees  part or all of the buffer space and the LSP resumes the operation.

If instead of 2 processes you have 3, the situation is more or less the same: a faster producer is blocked by a slower consumer. And obviously, a faster consumer is blocked by a slower producer if the pipe gets empty: just think of an interactive shell, waiting of the slowest producer of all: the user.

For example the following command:

```
$ yes | cat | more
```

Since `more` blocks when the screen is full, until the user presses a key, the `cat` process will fill its output buffer and stall, then the `yes` process will fill its buffer and also stall. Everything waiting for the user to continue, as it should be.

PS: As an interesting fact is: what happens when the `more` process ends? well, the right side of that pipe is closed, so the `cat` process will get a `SIGPIPE` signal (if it ever writes again in the pipe, and it will) and will die. The same will happen to the `yes` process. All processes die, as it should be.

Comment: Excellent description.  It was helpful for more to visualize the yes output with line numbers, $ yes | cat -n | more

Answer (score 2):

A has a pipe to B, and B has a pipe to C. Each pipe has a buffer; B and C block if they try to read, and there isn't any input available (end-of-stream counts as input). A and B block if they have output to write, but the pipe's buffer is full.

All three processes run concurrently, using as much CPU as they can. The OS blocks them in the read/write system call as necessary if the pipe buffer is exhausted/full respectively.

So, they're driven by both the consumer and producer, that is, the rate is the min of both the consuming rate and producing rate. If the consumer is faster, the performance is driven by the producer, and vv.